# URL to get the list of Wikipedia bots

Tags: wikipedia, bot

Is there an URL to retrieve the list of Wikipedia bots?
Those are users with the [bot flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBot_policy#The_.22bot.22_flag).
It could be HTML/XML or anything, but not the whole Wikipedia dump.

No such method in the [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php).

*Note: not all bots contain "bot" in their name, see for instance [CommonsDelinker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aCommonsDelinker).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* such method in the API, it's [`allusers`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?querymodules=allusers), which has a parameter `augroup` that you can use to get a list of all users in a specific group.

For example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&list=allusers&augroup=bot&aulimit=max

This will give you the first 500 bots. If you want to get all of them, you have to use [query-continue](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Continuing_queries).